# Show that $F_{cX + d}$ has the density function $f_{cX + d} = {1 \over |c|} f_X((t - d) / c).$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $cX + d$ be a random variable with $c, d \in \Bbb R, c \neq 0$. I already showed that the distribution function $F_{cX + d}$ is given by

$$F_{cX + d} =
\begin{cases}
F_X((t-d)/c),  & \text{if $c > 0,$} \\
1 - F_X((t-d)/c) + P(X = (t-d)/c), & \text{if $c < 0.$ }
\end{cases}$$

Now I want to assume that $X$ is absolutely continuous and has the density function $f_X$. I want to show that $cX + d$ is absolutely continuous too and has the density function

$$f_{cX + d} = {1 \over |c|} f_X((t - d) / c).$$

I thought it would be wise to take a look at the case $c > 0$ first.

We have

$$F_{cX + d}(t) = F_X((t -d) / c) = P(X \le (t-d)/c) = \int_{-\infty}^{(t-d)/c} f_X(s) \ d(s).$$

I guess we need to take the derivative here, but I don't know which kind of law I have to apply. Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: Try performing the natural substitution in your final integral

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What do you mean by "natural substitution" though?

Comment: Well natural/obvious thing to try at this stage would be the substitution $u(t) = (t-d)/c$

Comment: What is u(t)? A function?

Comment: A derivative might not exist, but fortunately you don't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that $c>0$ we have:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{|c|}f_{X}\left(\frac{t-d}{c}\right)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x-d}{c}}\frac{1}{c}f_{X}\left(s\right)d\left(cs+d\right)=$$$$\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x-d}{c}}f_{X}\left(s\right)ds=F_{X}\left(\frac{x-d}{c}\right)=F_{cX+d}\left(x\right)$$

This justifies the conclusion that $\frac{1}{|c|}f_{X}\left(\frac{t-d}{c}\right)$ serves as PDF for $cX+d$.

In the integral we applied the substitution $s=\frac{t-d}{c}$ (or $cs+d=t$ if you like). This gave us the first identity.